# Creating a table in SQL Server Express

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to setup a SQL database for a local program management and install system. I think i've created a basic serviceable schema that should work, but i'm unsure how to translate it to a CREATE TABLE command. Can someone help me with the translation and/or point me to resources that will?

Schema:

```
Programs(
    progID[key] (integer/index field?),
    name (text),
    desc (text), 
    iconFile (path to file),
    installScript (path to file))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following syntax:

```
create table programs (
    progid int primary key identity(1,1),
    name nvarchar(255),
    description nvarchar(500),
    iconFile nvarchar(255),
    installScript nvarchar(255)
)
```

The `primary key` sets the `progid` column to be the index column of the table. The `identity(1,1)` clause sets the `progid` to be an auto-incrementing field, starting at 1 and incrementing by 1 each time. Therefore, the following SQL enters the corresponding rows into `programs`:

```
insert into (name, description, iconfile, installscript)
values ('Name1', 'Test test', 'C:\file\path', 'C:\script\path')
insert into (name, description, iconfile, installscript)
values ('Name2', 'Test 123', 'C:\file\path1', 'C:\script\path2')

------------------------------------------------------------------
progid    name     description    iconfile        installscript
------------------------------------------------------------------
1         Name1    Test test      C:\file\path    C:\script\path
2         Name2    Test 123       C:\file\path1   C:\script\path2
```

Notice, also, that I used `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`. This is because `nvarchar` uses the Unicode character set, while `varchar` uses the ASCII character set. `nvarchar` is the recommended usage, since ASCII characters take no additional space in Unicode, but Unicode does allow for internationalization and obscure characters.

Comment: it came back with 'Error 156: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'desc'.'

Comment: Changed to `description`. `desc` is a reserved keyword in SQL, as in: `select * from programs order by progid desc` which would select all of the rows in `programs` and order them by the `progid` value in `desc`ending order.

Comment: Or if you really wanted to use "desc" instead of "description" you could enclose it in square brackets i.e. [desc] nvarchar(500). But generally life is easier if you can avoid reserved keywords entirely.

Comment: I've slightly modified my schema, but i can fix it myself :)

Answer (score 1):

Questions regarding SQL syntax should be directed over at [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com).

That said, if you have SQL Studio Management Express ([grab it from here](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?familyid=08E52AC2-1D62-45F6-9A4A-4B76A8564A2B&displaylang=en)), when you create your table structure, but before saving it, you can click on the "Generate Script" icon (it has a scroll with a disk on it), and it will show you the code it's about to execute.